# Trying to split a txt file into multiple variables

Tags: python, bioinformatics

So I'm making a program where it reads a text file and I need to separate all the info into their own variables. It looks like this:

```
>1EK9:A.41,52; B.61,74; C.247,257; D.279,289
ENLMQVYQQARLSNPELRKSAADRDAAFEKINEARSPLLPQLGLGAD
YTYSNGYRDANGINSNATSASLQLTQSIFDMSKWRALTLQEKAAGIQ
DVTYQTDQQTLILNTATAYFNVLNAIDVLSYTQAQKEAIYRQLDQTT
QRFNVGLVAITDVQNARAQYDTVLANEVTARNNLDNAVEQLRQITGN
YYPELAALNVENFKTDKPQPVNALLKEAEKRNLSLLQARLSQDLARE
QIRQAQDGHLPTLDLTASTGISDTSYSGSKTRGAAGTQYDDSNMGQN
KVGLSFSLPIYQGGMVNSQVKQAQYNFVGASEQLESAHRSVVQTVRS
SFNNINASISSINAYKQAVVSAQSSLDAMEAGYSVGTRTIVDVLDAT
TTLYNAKQELANARYNYLINQLNIKSALGTLNEQDLLALNNALSKPV
STNPENVAPQTPEQNAIADGYAPDSPAPVVQQTSARTTTSNGHNPFRN
```

The code after the > is a title, the next bit that looks like this "A.41,52" are numbered positions in the sequence I need to save to use, and everything after that is an amino acid sequence. I know how to deal with the amino acid sequence, I just need to know how to separate the important numbers in the first line.

In the past when I just had a title and sequence I did something like this:

```
for line in nucfile:
if line.startswith(">"):
    headerline=line.strip("\n")[1:]
else:
    nucseq+=line.strip("\n")
```

Am I on the right track here? This is my first time, any advice would be fantastic and thanks for reading :)

Comment: Pleasecheck my edit. The greater sign had got lost in blockquote interpretation, but only you know (of us two) which input is on which line. In your "past" code the content of `headerline` is then `'1EK9:...'` right? I would not used `nucseq += line.strip('\n')` when iterating over lines and this needs be done often, as strings in python are imutable and this creates some work ;-) maybe collect the stripped strings in a list (checp) and as postprocessing then join the into a final string, like `''.join(the_sequence)`

Comment: Thanks! Yes the greater sign was just the first line. So in place of nucseq += line.strip('\n')  you would use checp? What does that do? Thanks so much :)

Comment: sorry mobile device and fingers: that meant "cheap" as in a cheap and fast operation appending to a list. You then in the end write a string back ito your variable with this join call - that joins all sequence elements with the string it is a method of here a space - HTH and I see lots of answers already that is great.

Comment: I see, can you point me to an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the goal (and I think this post is more suitable for a comment, but I do not have enough privileges) but I think that the key to you solution is using `.split()`. You can then join the elements of the resulting list just by using + similar to this:

```
>>> result = line.split(' ')
>>> result
['1EK9:A.41,52;', 'B.61,74;', 'C.247,257;', 'D.279,289', 'ENLMQVYQQARLSNPELRKSAADRDAAFEKINEARSPLLPQLGLGAD', 'YTYSNGYRDANGINSNATSASLQLTQSIFDMSKWRALTLQEKAAGIQ', 'DVTYQTDQQTLILNTATAYFNVLNAIDVLSYTQAQKEAIYRQLDQTT', 'QRFNVGLVAITDVQNARAQYDTVLANEVTARNNLDNAVEQLRQITGN', 

'YYPELAALNVENFKTDKPQPVNALLKEAEKRNLSLLQARLSQDLARE', 'QIRQAQDGHLPTLDLTASTGISDTSYSGSKTRGAAGTQYDDSNMGQN', 'KVGLSFSLPIYQGGMVNSQVKQAQYNFVGASEQLESAHRSVVQTVRS', 'SFNNINASISSINAYKQAVVSAQSSLDAMEAGYSVGTRTIVDVLDAT', 'TTLYNAKQELANARYNYLINQLNIKSALGTLNEQDLLALNNALSKPV', 'STNPENVAPQTPEQNAIADGYAPDSPAPVVQQTSARTTTSNGHNPFRN']
    >>> result[3]+result[4]
    'D.279,289ENLMQVYQQARLSNPELRKSAADRDAAFEKINEARSPLLPQLGLGAD'
    >>>
```

etc.  You can also use the usual following syntax to extract the elements of the list that you need:

```
>>> result[5:]
['YTYSNGYRDANGINSNATSASLQLTQSIFDMSKWRALTLQEKAAGIQ', 'DVTYQTDQQTLILNTATAYFNVLNAIDVLSYTQAQKEAIYRQLDQTT', 'QRFNVGLVAITDVQNARAQYDTVLANEVTARNNLDNAVEQLRQITGN', 'YYPELAALNVENFKTDKPQPVNALLKEAEKRNLSLLQARLSQDLARE', 'QIRQAQDGHLPTLDLTASTGISDTSYSGSKTRGAAGTQYDDSNMGQN', 'KVGLSFSLPIYQGGMVNSQVKQAQYNFVGASEQLESAHRSVVQTVRS', 'SFNNINASISSINAYKQAVVSAQSSLDAMEAGYSVGTRTIVDVLDAT', 'TTLYNAKQELANARYNYLINQLNIKSALGTLNEQDLLALNNALSKPV', 'STNPENVAPQTPEQNAIADGYAPDSPAPVVQQTSARTTTSNGHNPFRN']
```

and join them together:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, result[5:])
'YTYSNGYRDANGINSNATSASLQLTQSIFDMSKWRALTLQEKAAGIQDVTYQTDQQTLILNTATAYFNVLNAIDVLSYTQAQKEAIYRQLDQTTQRFNVGLVAITDVQNARAQYDTVLANEVTARNNLDNAVEQLRQITGNYYPELAALNVENFKTDKPQPVNALLKEAEKRNLSLLQARLSQDLAREQIRQAQDGHLPTLDLTASTGISDTSYSGSKTRGAAGTQYDDSNMGQNKVGLSFSLPIYQGGMVNSQVKQAQYNFVGASEQLESAHRSVVQTVRSSFNNINASISSINAYKQAVVSAQSSLDAMEAGYSVGTRTIVDVLDATTTLYNAKQELANARYNYLINQLNIKSALGTLNEQDLLALNNALSKPVSTNPENVAPQTPEQNAIADGYAPDSPAPVVQQTSARTTTSNGHNPFRN'
```

remember that `+` on lists produces a list.

By the way I would not remove '\n' to start with as you may try to use it to extract the first line similar to the above with using space to extract "words".

UPDATE (starting from result):

```
#getting A indexes
letter_seq=result[5:]
ind=result[:4]
Aind=ind[0].split('.')[1].replace(';', '')

#getting one long letter seq
long_letter_seq=reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, letter_seq)

#extracting the final seq fromlong_letter_seq using Aind
output = long_letter_seq[int(Aind.split(',')[0]):int(Aind.split(',')[1])]
```

the last line is just a union of several operations that were also used earlier.

Same for B C D etc -- so a lot of manual work and calculations...

BE CAREFUL with indexes of A -- numbering in python starts from 0 which may not be the case in your numbering system.

The more elegant solution would be using `re` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find pettern using a mask, but this requires very well defined rules for how to look up the sequence needed.

UPDATE2: it is also not clear to me what is the role of spaces -- so far I removed them but they may matter when counting the letters in the original string.

Comment: Thanks! Okay to explain better, this part "A.41,52" tells me a position of interest in the following AAseq. It means amino acid 41 through 52 are important and I need to take those out to do further work with them.  so I need a way to save just those numbers so I can later say, ok program take out the sequence from 41-52 and do some work for me. Now, for your 1st bit of code you split the txt file by spaces, right? Does just make them a list now? For the 2nd bit, you are displaying the list from item 5 and onward? The last piece, I don't understand. Thanks again, this is very helpful :)

Comment: you would need further split the results of the first split using '.' as delimiter now(e.g list.split()[0].split('.')) and then work with the resulting list ... Then you cast the elements of this two level split list to int (int(list.split()[0].split('.')) and use them as indexes to extract sequences from the elements of the list from the first split.... yes it is a pain and there is no really efficient and nice way to do it.. A bit of advice -- for this like this use interdictive python -- it is much easier to control the result as your problem is data complexity and not the code per se....

Comment: On code -- the 1 part yes dividing by spaces. 2nd -- right as you said. reduce part -- just an easy way to stick all letter sequences (starting from 5) altogether instead of doing +'s multiple times (+ is an easy way to glue two lists together and letters sequences are lists in python. in my prev comment there is a typo in code -- should read list.split(' ')[0].split('.')

Comment: Okay thanks! For list.split(' ')[0].split('.') it will give me a list with everything separated to me to reference right? And then I can just grab pieces of the list as I need them?

Comment: Not exactly. list,split(' ') splits you the first big list, [0] extracts the first element, split('.') splits now the first element etc. I ll edit the code above to get the nums that I guess you want (I think I now understand the idea).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method.

split() allows you to specify the separator of your choice. Provided the sequence title (here 1EK9) is always separated from the rest of the sequence by a colon, you could first pass ":" as your separator. You could then split the remainder of the sequence to recover the numbered positions (e.g. A.41,52) using ";" as a separator.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding! My question with split is, does it give a list? In the examples I've seen it splits something like ['first thing', 'second thing','etc'] right? Could I then in turn make these items their own variable?

Comment: Yes Sammie, the output of list.split() is a list! You can easily check this out with the [type()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_type.htm)  method.

Comment: Ok great, so I would put variablename.split()? And then I could grab pieces of this list and make their own variable, right?

Comment: Yes Sammie. If newsequence=sequence.split(), you can then access newsequence[0], newsequence[1], and so on... For instance you could assign newsequence[0] to a variable called var by typing: var=newsequence[0]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is extract certain parts of the sequence based on their identifiers given to you on the first line (the line starting with `>`).

This line contains your title, then a sequence name and the data range you need to extract.

Try this:

```
sequence_pairs = {}

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   header_line = next(f)
   sequence = f.read()
   title,components = header_line.split(':')
   pairs = components.split(';')
   for pair in pairs:
      start,end = pair[2:-1].split(',')
      sequence_pars[pair[:1]] = sequence[start:int(end)+1]

for sequence,data in sequence_pairs.iteritems():
    print('{} - {}'.format(sequence, data))
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you be willing to explain to me what these steps do? I'm sorry it's a little above my understanding. :)

Comment: Also, I've plugged it in to see what this gets me, but I get the error "Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data"       Do you know what that means? lol I'm sorry Im not very good at this :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer may be very good to tackle the assumed problem in it's entirety - but the OP has requested for pointers or an example of the tpyical split-unsplit transform which is often so successful I hereby provide some ideas and working code to show this (based on the example of the question).

So let us focus on the else branch below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
nuc_seq = []  # a list
title_token = '>'
with open('some_file_of_a_kind.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        s_line = line.strip()  # this strips whitespace
        if line.startswith(title_token):
            headerline = line.strip("\n")[1:]
        else:
            nuc_seq.append(s_line)  # build list

# now nuc_seq is a list of strings like:
# ['ENLMQVYQQARLSNPELRKSAADRDAAFEKINEARSPLLPQLGLGAD',  
#  'YTYSNGYRDANGINSNATSASLQLTQSIFDMSKWRALTLQEKAAGIQ',
#  ...
# ]

demo_nuc_str = ''.join(nuc_seq)
# now: 
# demo_nuc_str == 'ENLMQVYQQARLSNPELRKSAADRDAAFEKINEARSPLLPQLGLGADYTYSNGYR ...'
```

That is fast and widely deployed paradigm in Python programming (and programming with powerful datatypes in general).

If the split-unsplit ( a.k.a. join) method is still unclear, just ask or try to sear SO on excellent answers to related questions.

Also note, that there is no need to `line.strip('\n')` as `\n`is considered whitespace like `' '` (string with a space only) or a tabulator `'\t'`, sample:

```
>>> a = ' \t \n '
>>> '+'.join(a.split())
''
```

So the "joining character" only appears, if there are at least two element sto join and in this case, strip removed all whits space and left us with the empty string.

**Upate:**

As requested a further analysis of the "coordinate part" in the line called headline of the question:

```
>1EK9:A.41,52; B.61,74; C.247,257; D.279,289
```

If you want to retrieve the:

```
A.41,52; B.61,74; C.247,257; D.279,289
```

and assume you have (as above the complete line in headline string):

```
title, coordinate_string = headline.split(':')
# so now title is '1EK9' and
# coordinates == 'A.41,52; B.61,74; C.247,257; D.279,289'
```

Now split on the semi colons, trim the entries:

het_seq = [z.strip() for z in coordinates.split(';')]
   # now het_seq == ['A.41,52', 'B.61,74', 'C.247,257', 'D.279,289']

If 'a', 'B', 'C', and 'D' are well known dimensions, than you can "lose" the ordering info from input file (as you could always reinforce what you already know ;-) and might map the coordinats as key: (ordered coordinate-pair):

```
>>> coord_map = dict(
        (a, tuple(int(k) for k in bc.split(','))) 
         for a, bc in (abc.split('.') for abc in het_seq))
>>> coord_map
{'A': (41, 52), 'C': (247, 257), 'B': (61, 74), 'D': (279, 289)}
```

In context of a micro program:

```
#! /usr/bin/enc python
from __future__ import print_function

het_seq = ['A.41,52', 'B.61,74', 'C.247,257', 'D.279,289']

coord_map = dict(
    (a, tuple(int(k) for k in bc.split(',')))
    for a, bc in (abc.split('.') for abc in het_seq))
print(coord_map)
```

yields:

```
{'A': (41, 52), 'C': (247, 257), 'B': (61, 74), 'D': (279, 289)}
```

Here one might write this explicit a nested for loop but it is a late european evening so trick is to read it from right:

1. for all elements of het_seq
2. split on the dot and store left in a and right in b
3. than further split the bc into a sequence of k's, convert to integer and put into tuple (ordered pair of integer coordinates)
4. arrived on the left you build a tuple of the a ("The dimension like 'A' and the coordinate tuple from 3.

In the end call the dict() function that constructs a dictionary using here the form dict(key_1, value_1, hey_2, value_2, ...) which gives {key_1: value1, ...}

So all coordinates are integers, stored ordered pairs as tuples.

I'ld prefer tuples here, although split() generates lists, because

1. You will keep those two coordinates not extend or append that pair
2. In python mapping and remapping is often performed and there a hashable (that is immutable type) is ready to become a key in a dict.

One last variant (with no knoted comprehensions):

```
coord_map = {}
for abc in het_seq:
    a, bc = abc.split('.')
    coord_map[a] = tuple(int(k) for k in bc.split(','))
print(coord_map)
```

The first four lines produce the same as above minor obnoxious "one liner" (that already had been written on three lines kept together within parentheses).

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, and it prints out just my sequence. My next question is how to I get the "A.41,52" parts out of that?

Comment: Wait I think I get it now

Comment: That is good - did not watch comments while typing the "answer" to the "next question" maybe it helps what I wrote - will write some comments to the last unmapping splitting step

Comment: No this is way better. I was going in a different direction, I really really appreciate all the help!!!

Comment: Great. You're welcome. Happy Python hacking to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you are trying to process a Fasta like file and so the way I would do it is to first get the header and separate the pieces with Regex. Following that you can store the A:42.52 B... in a list for easy access. The code is as follows.

```
import re

def processHeader(line):
     positions = re.search(r':(.*)', line).group(1)
     positions = positions.split('; ')
     return positions

dnaSeq = ''
positions = []
with open('myFasta', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          if '>' in line:
              positions = processHeader(line)
          else:
              dnaSeq += line.strip()
```